# Is there a meaning to the 6 stroke component that 恵, 専, and 敷 share?

Tags: kanji

The three kanji 恵, 専, and 敷 share the same first 6 strokes. Using the traditional radicals I could describe them as being composed "一, 日, 丨..." at the start and then finishing "...心", "...寸", "...⼂, 方, 攵" respectively.  Are the first 6 strokes derived from some older kanji? If so, does this kanji have a meaning and what would it be in Japanese?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going back to [*kyūjitai*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ky%C5%ABjitai),

- The first 8 strokes of「惠」and「專」share「叀」
- The first 6 strokes of「敷」uses「甫」

which are different components.

---

「叀」depicts an ancient type of ceramic tile used for weaving or spinning thread.

## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[鐵](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)104.1
[合集32985](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=32985&jgwfl=)</kbd>    
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

[image]

「叀」serves as two different phonetic components, which may hint at the original and extended meanings of「叀」in some characters:

- 「[叀]{せん}」 in「[專]{せん}」

  - *(Ceramic) tile* is now written as「[磚]{せん}」
  - *To spin/turn* is now written as「[轉]{てん}」([Shinjitai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinjitai):「転」)
- 「[叀]{けい}」([*Fanqie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanqie): 胡桂切) in「[惠]{けい}」

  - *[Tassel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tassel)* is now written as「[穗]{すい}」(Shinjitai:「穂」);
  - *Fine cloth* is now written as「[繐]{ けい}」

---

「甫」was originally「⿱屮田」, which depicted a vegetable <sub>(plants「屮」)</sub> garden <sub>(field「田」)</sub>. This word is now written as「圃」.

## <kbd>商
甲
[image]
[後](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1.31.1
[合集7897](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=7897&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>篆
[image]
說文解字</kbd>
　<kbd>現代
楷
[image]</kbd>

> Due to historical development, the characters/components「田」,「用」, and the top of「周」will appear as graphical variations of each other in the modern script.「用」is the shape that appears in the modern form of「甫」.

The character「[敷]{ふ}」meaning *spread* was developed through

1. 「尃」, semantic「又」(*picture of a hand*; semantic variant「寸」) and phonetic「[甫]{ふ}」;
2. Change to a shape variant「旉」;
3. Addition of an *action* semantic component「攵」(*picture of a hand holding a whip*).

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

Comment: Errata: should be the first **7** strokes of「敷」.

Answer (score 4):

So, actually 敷 has a different origin from the other two kanji.

Looking at [wiktionary entry for 敷](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%95%B7) in fact tells us that composition is comes from `旉攵`, the first of which is composed of `甫方`. Notice the importance of the extra `⼂`.

Doing the same for [恵](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%81%B5) or [専](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B0%82) gives us . But actually more importantly is the note in wiktionary that,  both those kanji are 新字体, aka Japanese simplifications of originals: 惠 and 專. Note how the part in question is now very different and is now this character: [叀](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%80).

As for the meaning, I'm not sure the meaning of these components is valuable to understanding the 3 characters above, but they can also be read on the wiktionary entries.